# Non-discrete locally compact Hausdorff groups which do not satisfy the second axiom of countability

Tags: measure-theory, soft-question, topological-groups

I think *non-discrete* locally compact Hausdorff groups which do not satisfy the second axiom of countability are pain in the ass. The major trouble is that the Haar measures on them are not necessarily $\sigma$-finite.
I wish we could do math all right without them.
Are there important examples of such groups which we cannot dispense with?

Comment: Any uncountable discrete groups for example. What you should note is that each such group has an open, closed, $\sigma$-compact subgroup. Hence, if $G$ is connected, it is automatically $\sigma$ compact. Also observe that $\sigma$- compactness is **implied** by second countability, but not vice versa. Take e.g. the uncountable product $\prod_{I\in \Bbb{R}} [0,1]$. This is $\sigma$ compact, but not even first countable.

Comment: @PhoemueX Sorry. I forgot to assume the obvious condition that they are *non-discrete*.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in my comment, there is a large supply of compact, but not second countable groups, e.g. every uncountable product

$$
\prod_{i \in I} G_i,
$$

where $I$ is uncountable and each $G_i$ is a compact group consisting of more than one element. These groups do not even fulfill the **first** axiom of accountability.

But from the formulation of your question, it is not entirely clear if you want to have examples. of relevant groups which are not second countable, or which are not $\sigma$-compact.

Here, you should observe that second countability implies $\sigma$-compactness, but not vice versa (as the example of the product of compact groups shows).

Comment: This is a soft question, of course. Are there important examples of such groups that we cannot dispense with?
It's *very* tedious to treat such groups without assuming the second axiom. Is it worth the effort?